# call method in controller different id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have foreach

```
@foreach (var produkt in ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts){    
<button id="submitButton" value="@produkt.ProductId">Add to Cart</button>
    }
```

and call method jquery ajax

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {


      var id
      var quantity = 1;

            $('#submitButton').click(

/*error dont work read value from button id */
      var id = $('#submitButton').attr('value'); /*I dont know how to read difrent id for any product*/ 


                function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Action("AddToCart2", "Cart")',
                        data: { id: id, quantity: quantity },
                        success: function (result) {
                            $("#mydiv").load(location.href + " #mydiv");
                        },

                        error: function (abc) {
                            alert(abc.statusText);
                        },
                    });
                })
        })
    </script>
```

I dont know how to read diffrent #submitbutton for one to product becouse read only one first element.

**var id = $('#submitButton').attr('value');** is only one but I have for example 20 elelements, have i can read difrent element id for @foreach (var produkt in ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts)

Any idea?

Comment: `foreach ...  { .. id=submitButton .. }` all your buttons have the same ID.  IDs must be unique.   So `$("#submitButton").attr("value")` will *always* be the first button.  Change to use a class and move the `var id=` *inside* the click handler to `var id = $(this).attr("value")`

Comment: $(dokument).gotowa(funkcja () {
        var id;
        var quantity = 1;

        $('#submitButton').click(

        id = $('#submitButton').attr('value'); /*I dont know how to read difrent id for any product*/
        function () {
               // do something
                });
            })
    })
</script> dont work

Comment: @JanuszSzum just change ` id="submitButton"` to `class="submitButton"` and then do `$('.submitButton').click`, and then `var id = $(this).attr('value')`

Comment: You've missed the most important part: **Change to use a class**

Comment: thx  Carsten Løvbo Andersen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per freedomn-m's comment, your code will generate buttons with same ids, and ids should be unique. You can also directly assign function to it:

```
@foreach (var produkt in ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts) {    
    <button onclick='addToCart("@produkt.ProductId")'>Add to Cart</button>
}
```

And define the function:

```
function addToCart(productId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("AddToCart2", "Cart")',
        data: {
            id: productId
            quantity: 1
        },
        success: function(result) {
            $("#mydiv").load(location.href + " #mydiv");
        },

        error: function(abc) {
            alert(abc.statusText);
        },
    });
})
```

Comment: Its nice, 
i have error ReferenceError: addToCart is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: make sure you had defined function properly.

Comment: `addToCart` won't be available from onclick= if you've put `function addToCart` inside a doc.ready - which this answer does not suggest you do, but you might have done without realising.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // Initialization
            var id;
            var quantity = 1;

            $('.submitButton').click(
                    function () {
                var id = $(this).attr('value')
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Action("AddToCart2", "Cart")',
                        data: { id: id, quantity: quantity },
                        success: function (result) {
                            $("#mydiv").load(location.href + " #mydiv");
                        },

                        error: function (abc) {
                            alert(abc.statusText);
                        },
                    });

                })
        })
    </script>
```

Its work for me.
Thx